# Using regex to parse different locale/langage?

Tags: java, regex

I have some text that comes back in different languages.  Right now, the text comes back from a client in the form of (en-us aka english for US):

```
Stuff here to keep.

-- Delete Here --
all of this below
gets
deleted
```

I'm using a regex to match "Delete Here" and snip everything at that line and below it leaving on the "Stuff here to keep."

The "Delete Here:" is the text that can come back in any language.

So for Italian the key words to match for are "Elimina qui":

```
Stuff here to keep (in italian)

-- Elimina qui --
all of this bellow
gets
deleted
```

My regex usses something like this to match the "Delete Here" but how can I get this to work with other languages?

Do I ineed a look up dictionary for each word combo "Delete", "Here", (there are more to match one) etc,.???  How can I make this solution work for all languages?

> **NOTE:** this is a very, very simple example.  the "-- Delete Here --" is just one pattern I have to match.  Other patterns could be just "Delete Here".  And there are other patterns like "Delete All Below"
>   (again for literary context there are other text patterns that I have
>   to match in multiple languages).

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)-+ *Delete Here *-+", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
      // Perform Magic!
}
```

Comment: Are there any sections of `-- whatever --` that should stay? If not then maybe try `-- *[^-]+ *--`.

Comment: the issue is that I can't always rely on the dashes.  that is just one pattern.  some patterns don't contain dashes but I have to match in other languages (I made some edits above to describe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use OR in regex

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)-+ *(?:Delete Here|Elimina qui) *-+", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

but be carefull if you have many (hunderds ) OR strings it could be problem from performance point of view. For such number is better to make simple pattern to retrieve string between "--"s and use a set to check if it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have other sections of your data that have consectutive dashes one way would be use a negated character class to match between those dashes.

Another possible option would be to use `\p{L}` which matches any kind of letter from any language.

```
-- *\p{L}+ \p{L}+ *--
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/iO5mY5)

Comment: this is a great idea.  however, the dashes are not always going to be there.  that is just one pattern.  it could come back as just "Delete Here" with no dashes.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a job for regular expression, unless you want to translate Delete Here in all language and store them in your expression which seems insane to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, whether its work for you, but I captured Bengali numbers `১, ২, ৩, ৪`,  this way :

```
String bengaliString = "গণি মিয়া একজন গরীব কৃষক। তার ২ বিঘা জমি এবং ১ টি মাত্র গরু আছে। "; 



final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bengaliString);
```

Hope, this helps someone.